# Two constructors that do different things but take the same data type

Tags: java, constructor

I have recently ran into this problem with my `MorseString` class. I have two different constructors that do different things, but take the same data type:

```
/*
 * Constructor that takes the Morse Code as a String as a parameter
 */

public MorseString(String s) {
    if(!isValidMorse(s)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("s is not a valid Morse Code");
    }
    // ...
}
```

and

```
/*
 * Constructor that takes the String as a parameter and converts it to Morse Code
 */

public MorseString(String s) {
    // ...
}
```

I came up with this solution:

```
public MorseString(String s, ParameterType type) {
    if(type == ParameterType.CODE) {
        if(!isValidMorse(s)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("s is not a valid Morse Code");
        }
        // Constructor that takes Morse
    } else {
        // Constructor that takes String
    }
}
```

But it looks ugly. Any other solutions?

Comment: Use functions instead of constructors.

Comment: It sure is ugly, but having 2 methods/constructors with the same signature is not possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review. It would be more suited to [codereview](codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Gumbo a function named `toMorseCode(String s)` and another named `setMorseCode(String s)`. Seems alot cleaner than a constructor that takes 2 parameters and makes a decision based off the second parameter.

Comment: Its more of a design question than code review question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since one of the constructors is expecting ready-made Morse Code data (so it is more like a "constructor" - literally constructing an object from the data), and the other has to do some conversion, it might make more sense to make a static factory method called something like `convert`:

```
/*
 * Constructor that takes the Morse Code as a String as a parameter
 */

public MorseString(String s) {
    if(!isValidMorse(s)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("s is not a valid Morse Code");
    }
    // ...
}

/*
 * Factory method that takes the String as a parameter and converts it to Morse Code
 */

public static MorseString convert(String s) {
    // ...
    return new MorseString(convertedString);
}
```

So if you had a valid morse code string, you use the constructor to turn it into an object.  However if you have data that needs conversion, you would call the static factory method:

```
MorseString ms = MorseString.convert(myString);
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Get rid of your constructors and use instead some other approach, such as

1) A [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), so you'd have methods like this:

```
class MorseString {
    private MorseString(){};
    public static MorseString getFromCode(String s) {
        // ...
    }
    public static MorseString getFromString(String s) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Usage: MorseString.getFromCode(foo);
```

or

2) A [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), so you'd have methods like this

```
class MorseString {
    private MorseString(){};
    static class Builder {
       Builder initFromCode(String code) {
          // ..
          return this;
       }
       Builder initFromString(String str) {
          // ..
          return this;
       }
       MorseString build() {
          // ..
       }
    }
}

// Usage: MorseString.Builder.initFromCode(foo).build();
```

A builder is good if you have a highly complex creation logic, lots of parameters, having objects with only some of their information in mid-creation, some preliminary validations etc. A factory method is lighter approach for a situation where you have multiple ways of creating your object with slightly varying parameters.

Comment: This is probably a better solution to avoid the ambiguity on what type of String you are passing in.